# crashing when writing to a vb string passed to c++ dll

Tags: c++, vb.net

Using visual studio 2012, I need to pass a string to a DLL in C++.  To do this, in VB I create a string by `s = new string("  ", 100)`, which creates a string `s` of 100 spaces.  I then pass this string which will be written into with less than 100 chars and it gets passed back with the new string as expected.

in the declare function I use

```
...,s as string...
```

And NOT:

```
by reference s as string
```

However, if before passing this string but after creating it as described above I write a short string in VB into it such as `s = "hi fox"` and then pass it into the DLL and write into it with a string longer then 6 chars, it crashes!!

The lesson seems to be that after creating a blank string with the `new string()` function, you cannot write a shorter string into it.  It is as if the memory allocated to the string in VB becomes not the 100 chars that you created the string with but the size of the memory of `s` is now the size of the shorter string.

If this is reasonable behavior, I would like to know.  It is quite different from the `new` function of C++, in which the size of memory allocated is not changed by the size of the array you write to it.

Thank you for any response and interest you may have.

Comment: Please show us the code in C++.  Your issue has nothing to do with writing shorter strings inside of a buffer that is big enough to hold a longer string.

Comment: Chances are your visual basic string looks nothing like a c++ string, so attempting to treat it like one will be problematic. How are you marshalling your data  / calling your DLL?

Comment: After `s = "hi fox"`, `s` no longer refers to the original 100-char string... it refers to the string `"hi fox"` (which is 6 chars).

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: to paul, I think the buffer is no longer 100 chars but the size of the shorter string.

Comment: to immibis  you are exactly right it is behaving as if the memory allocated to the string s is not the 100 chars that I created with the new string() function.  this seems to be strange behavior to me who is somewhat used to the new in c++ which creates a memory size at the time of the function call and does not change that if you simply write something into it shorter than than the size you created..

Comment: to red alert. when looking at memory ( in dll) the memory has the old string and also what I added to it.  it is vb that is saying that I overstepped my bounds and in fact crashes the system.  to all I will live with this of course but I don't have to like it(lol)  thank you all, david

Comment: @david - It seems to me, that if the C++ function is declared expecting a buffer of a specific size it will try and take that size. Try padding the string to 100 characters. Remember that the C++ function will probably require a character 0 to terminate the string.  On a side note use `@username` to address a comment to a specific user.

Comment: You should be using BSTR in C++ and not char*. Please show us the C++ code.

Comment: @tinstaafl  I believe that the dll receives a location (it is declared with char*) that has 100 chars of 20  space   and the string hi fox with the terminating 0 inserted is in the first 7 places.  so vb does the right thing in passing the string to the dll.  what it doesn't tell me that vb has redefined the concept of "new" so that the buffer now has only 6 chars available and if  you overwrite this you are in biggg trouble; I wonder if they knew --no pun intended -- what they were doing. thank you for your side note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike C++, a VB string is not stored with the string header, and contains no terminating zero. When you assign "hi fox" to the string, the 100-character memory location is no longer available, replaced by the 6 character string. You might be able use a byte array in place of a string for this parameter, but you should be careful of 2-byte characters.

Comment: I really have no issue with what or how vb stores the string.  my issue is with their redefining the use of "new" established in C C++.

Comment: My point is that when you assign a value to a vb.net string, it effectively creates a new string of that length, and does not retain the unused bytes like C or C++. That's just how it works.

Comment: thank you! I guess it was just a bit of a surprise to me, but once you know it you can use it. again appreciate your comments.  david